# Is there any other size tires that will fit on a 27 x 1 1/4 rim?

Tags: tire

I live in a city with plenty of cycling shops, but they are all out of 27 x 1 1/4 tires. Each shop gives me a different answer about the possibility of using a different size of tire. Can I fit a different size onto an old 27 x 1 1/4 rim?

Comment: You need a 27-inch tire.  The width, within reason, does not matter that much -- you could likely use anything between roughly 1" and 1 3/4".  But it's hard to imagine that no shop can get their hands on a 27x1 1/4" tire -- it was at one time the most popular "adult" size tire.  (Unlike 26" tires, all 27" tires (except for one or two very weird cases) have the same rim diameter, and are interchangeable provided the width is not too far off.)

Comment: I doubt its a case of can't get their hands on it, but moreso a case of they need to order it. If you have a bike shop that does used bikes or sees a lot of older bikes, thats where I'd check for having it on hand. A shop that only has the newest latest greatest stuff might not have it on hand, but they should be able to order it.

Answer (score 11):

You need 27 x (some number of inches given as a fraction). So 27x 1 1/8 would fit, 27 x 1 1/4 would fit, etc. Other sizes won't fit. As dlu's answer points out, an easy way to get this right is to ask for ISO 630 tires.

That being said,  27 x 1 1/4 tires are still made in plenty by brands like Continental, Bontrager, etc. so your bike shop should easily be able to order one for you in a few days, or you can buy them online.

See [Sheldon Brown's page](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) for details on how tire sizing for bicycles is a mess.

"Brown's Law Of Tire Sizing:

If two tires are marked with sizes that are mathematically equal,
but one is expressed as a decimal and the other as a fraction,
these two tires will not be interchangeable."

Sheldon has another [interesting note](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/harris/tires/630.html): Very old (60's) 27" rims had straight sides versus modern hooked sides, so they can't run as high pressure. However, he says if you get a tire which says hook edge rims only, you can put it on an older straight rim, just not at as high of a pressure.

Finally, tubes for 27 x 1 1/4 tires are a different matter. You can use 700c tubes in 27 x 1 1/4 tires (The right size should be 700 x 28-32 ish -- the boxes will be marked accordingly depending on the brand).

Comment: Thanks. I am reading Sheldon's article right now, which is fun. I wish I had the chance to meet that man when he was alive. As for ordering the tires, I will do so, but you know how hard it is to wait when you've been working on something and want to ride it RIGHT NOW. Sigh.

Comment: You might ask some of the local shops if they have some sitting in the trash that would work until they get some in…

Comment: I suppose you could look at your brakes and see if you could get about 4 mm more reach, and then go looking on craigslist for a set of inexpensive 700c wheels…

Comment: That is an option, but honestly, its not that hard to get 27 x 1 1/4 tires these days with a little foresight that i think the cost of conversion is not worth it.

Comment: Agreed. Just trying to think about what could be done TODAY. And if the bike will accommodate the change without a cascade of other changes it might be nice to have the additional tire options that come with 700c wheels.

Answer (score 7):

The most reliable way to compare tire sizes is to use the ISO / ERTRO sizing. Most tires will be marked with it. Look for a number like this "32-630" (the ISO equivalent of 27 x 1 1/4). As long as you the second number, the bead seat diameter in millimeters, is 630 the tire will fit on the rim. The first number, 32 in this case, is the width of the tire, also in millimeters. That number can vary a bit without problem. If you go much wider you may have issues with clearance at the chain stays or perhaps the fork crown. Within reason, narrower won't be a problem.

27 x 1 1/4 seems to be the most common 27 inch size still made, but there are some others. Take a look at the [27 inch listings](https://www.biketiresdirect.com/search/27in-road-tires) at Bike Tires Direct for example.

Comment: +1 for ISO / ERTRO. 27 x 1 1/4 is by far the most common, but 1 1/8 is easy to find as well.

Answer (score -5):

Dude , 27 x 1 1/4 tires are quite available on the net....in this day & age local shops might defer to all whatever is the new thing 28" et cet & not stock as many 27 x 1 1/4 if at all due to the local demand...I have heard that you might go a size smaller but that's on you NEVER GO Larger....Smaller or larger equally...if you have to zip & shake to avoid a spill & the tire comes off the rim & you get T-Boned..& sue the tire manfact. their atty. will just hold up your rim & the tire (size) you had on to Da Judge & you lose & have to pay the other's attys fees & costs..SAME with Tires that state "Hooked Rims are necess for a proper fit...Smooth side'd rims not reccm"d" . If there is NO warning , no red flag..about the tire & hooked rims...don't worry...ONLY if there IS.. Bike Co's might tell you that they have sold thousands of Hooked rim Tires to smooth sided rim Owners with no complaints  I REFER you to above "zip & shake"..If a Tire Manfg makes a note of "proper fit with hooked rim" , that's to CYA himself not to help you...it's a red flag warning ! Proceed at your own expense....Cause that's what their Atty will hold up to Da Judge...Your Smooth Sided Rim & Their warning...Again "U" Lose.......BEST , go with your tire size , your rim size & your tube size....They should all be the same . NOT what someone is trying to sell you to clear off what has been sitting on their shelves...Riding a Bike , everyone is coming at you..no need for you to help them take you out

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.  The question posted was  "Is there any other size tires that will fit on a 27 x 1 1/4 rim?"     Please use [edit] to focus on answering the question.   You may benefit from reading the [tour] and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer